# AVAudioEngine causes AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInInputChain error on iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, audiokit

I am using `SFSpeechRecognizer` and noticed this error showing up on iOS >= 13.

This is my code for starting recognition process:

```c
- (void)startRecording:(BOOL)collectPartialResults {    
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&error];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];

    AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = _audioEngine.inputNode;

    _recognitionRequest = [SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest new];
    _recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = collectPartialResults;

    _recognitionTask = [_internalRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:_recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
       // ...
    }];

    AVAudioFormat *format = [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];

    @try {
        [inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:format block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
            [_recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
        }];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", exception.userInfo);
        [self sendStartRecordingErrorMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", exception.userInfo]];
        return;
    }

    NSError *startError;
    [_audioEngine startAndReturnError:&startError];

    if (startError != nil) {
        [self sendStartRecordingErrorMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", startError.userInfo]];
    }
}
```

This works for one or two times, but eventually leads to this error:

```
AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1397:Initialize: (err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInInputChain(ThisGraph, *GetInputNode())): error -10851
```

caused by this line: `[_audioEngine startAndReturnError:&startError];`

I have no idea what does this error mean. My code is almost the same as [official example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Listings/SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017110-SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_6).

I've tried several things such as:

- using `outputFormatForBus` instead of `inputFormatForBus` for
  `installTapOnBus`,
- using different `audioSession` mode (`AVAudioSessionModeVoicePrompt`),
- calling `[audioEngine reset]`    before starting recoding process

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. For me the solution was to use a new AVAudioEngine for each recording.

In your example:

```
- (void)startRecording:(BOOL)collectPartialResults {
  _audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you show your exact code for whole process? Now it's giving me this super-clear error: +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"

Comment: Sorry, can't share my code. But `kAFAssistantErrorDomain` looks like it's part of the `Speech` framework and not of `AVFoundation`. So it's probably an unrelated error.

Comment: I made some findings - it seems you should not start recording unless previous one did not return final results. If I do this way I do not encounter this error.

Comment: You should get a medal as I was debugging for few hours and looked all over and only your soimple answer acctually solved my issue. Thanks!